# Is there a way in Keycloak to store an Access Token additionally into an external DB?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, access-token

Due to a migration from a legacy/home-made OAuth solution to Keycloak, it is necessary to write the access tokens into the original DB in the first step.

Is there a way to get/intercept the access token in a SPI? I would also have to store the token only **additionally** and **not** replace the token in the session in the infinispan memory.

I have a Keycloak in an embedded Spring Boot Container and wrote a CustomerStorage SPI already which works as expected but I fail at this problem.

Maybe there is a better solution than Keycloak?

Comment: An access token is supposed to live for a very short time. Is it a good idea to persist something that will expire very quickly ?

Comment: I know, but as I said it's a legacy application, I want to avoid rebuilding everything. It is currently implemented in such a way that the tokens are stored in a MongoDB and when accessing e.g. a Rest API it is checked in the DB if the token is valid.